# Swift 3: popover connection from button inside dynamic uitableviewcell to uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uipopovercontroller

Hello I'm trying to connect a viewcontroller with a uibutton inside a table view cell as a popover connection. I have a small view controller with 2 buttons inside which should be my popover. And I have a tableview with many many cells and buttons inside those cells. When the user clicks on a specific button I want to open a popover with a anchor on the clicked button like the default behavior of a popover connection on static content.

But when dealing with dynamic content I'm getting this error in my storyboard: 
Couldn't compile connection ...

Here is a little sample of what I'm trying to do and the error I get: 
[image]

I don't want to use dirty hacks like hidden 1 px buttons and something like this. I tried to create a custom segue but it's also not working good.

So what is the best way to achieve this?

This is how this example looks like as code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell

        let button = cell.customButton

        return cell
    }

}


import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var customButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {


    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you want to use uiviewcontroller inside your cell?

Comment: i don't want to use a uiviewcontroller inside my cell. I also don't get the question right

Comment: Present the popover in code.  You can't use a view in a prototype cell as the anchor view for a popover in a storyboard.

Comment: yes that's the problem. so how can I present the popover in code on the right place inside the viewcontroller? because I cant present it inside the cell or not? I've update the post to show so code of this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your popover view is only with buttons, you can use `UIAlertController`, but the arrow would only appear in iPad

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
alertVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
//setup
if let popoverController = alertVC.popoverPresentationController  {
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .any
        popoverController.sourceView = self
        popoverController.sourceRect = self.bounds
    }
}
tableVC.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: yeah but the buttons have very complex functions inside them

Comment: well, if your button UI isn't complex, that has nothing to do with your logic inside button.

Comment: the button is also a custom button

Comment: From where you get object of tableviewcontroller here??